# Start firefox using apparmor (for extra security)

Tags: firefox, security, apparmor

I'm having some trouble starting firefox with apparmor. Here's what I've run:

```
$ sudo aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
$ firefox
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox: error while loading shared libraries: libpthread.so.0: cannot stat shared object: Permission denied
```

Does firefox now work out of the box with the configs provided by ubuntu? Do I need any extra configs?

Comment: You don't need any extra configs. It should launch as usual. What version of Ubuntu and Firefox do you have ? Firefox from repo? or deb?

Answer (score -3):

I think you should run firefox as **root** too because you run apparmor as root.
maybe thats why it says

> Premission denied

`sudo firefox`

Comment: Ack! Security vulnerability at twelve o'clock! Seriously, don't run Firefox as root, because drive-by malware can murder your entire system. And, `sudo` isn't meant to be used for graphical apps.

Comment: Never run your browser with root privileges unless you're operating a honeypot to attract malware!